# Can someone tell me where my error is in this formula

Tags: google-sheets

[image]I have a filter function that i am trying to use to pull data from sheet named "SOLD-DATABASE" by date range.6  Sheet has data from A2 to O with the date I want to filter by in M.  Here is my formula;

```
=filter(SOLD-DATABASE!A2:O, SOLD-DATABASE!M2:M>= date(2,1,22), SOLD-DATABASE!M2:M<=date(2,28,22))
```

Getting error message that I have mismatched range?
Thanks for all help!

Comment: Share a sample workbook so that we can check.

Comment: `Date()` function argument is wrong. It will be year, month, day. Try `date(2022,1,2)`

Comment: Thanks still getting error message for mismatch range

Comment: Another thing is, due to regional settings you may need semicolon `;` instead of comma `,`. So, give a try to `=filter(SOLD-DATABASE!A2:O; SOLD-DATABASE!M2:M>= date(2022;2;1); SOLD-DATABASE!M2:M<=date(2022;2;28))`

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the sheet name =filter('sold-database'!A2:O, 'sold-database'!M2:M>= date(2,1,22), 'sold-database'!M2:M<=date(2,28,22))  To have got this far I think you must have named ranges called SOLD and DATABASE otherwise I can't make sense of it

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER('SOLD-DATABASE'!A2:O; 
        'SOLD-DATABASE'!M2:M>=DATE(2022; 2; 1); 
        'SOLD-DATABASE'!M2:M<=DATE(2022; 2; 28))
```

or:

```
=FILTER('SOLD-DATABASE'!A2:O; 
   TEXT('SOLD-DATABASE'!M2:M; "emm")="202202")
```